# How do I utilize suexec to allow a php script to run a linux command?

Tags: sudo, suexec

I would like to execute a php script in a browser that will in turn execute a single linux command and return its output. When I first decided to test this out I created this:

```
<?php
$command = "ls";
exec($command, $output);
print_r($output);
?>
```

That worked just fine. But when I changed $command to the command I really wanted to run:

```
$command = "/etc/init.d/mycontrollerd status /etc/mycontrollerconfig";
```

it gave me this output:

```
Array ( [0] => You need root privileges to run this script )
```

I have been advised to use suexec. However after examining the man page I can't even tell where to begin. Of course I don't want to create a security risk. So can someone give me the recipe to make my command run and return its output?

BTW, this is on a basic LAMP box running Ubuntu.

EDIT: @womlbe below recommends sudo over suexec. With security still being paramount, how could I do this?

Comment: Whoever advised you to use `suexec` should have their breathing privs revoked.  Use `sudo`, it's what it's designed for.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, suexec will not grant root privileges (or the privileges of the apache user).

To use suexec, in its simplest form, I believe that you would:

1. If you are running FastCGI, you will define the path to suexec (I don't believe suexec works for mod_php) (in httpd.conf):

   e.g. `FastCgiSuexec /usr/sbin/suexec` (which may require changing the permissions on suexec). There is a brief, but somewhat dated, overview [here](http://www.alain.knaff.lu/howto/PhpSuexec/).
2. Add a line to your VirtualHost to specify the user you want to run as:

   `SuexecUserGroup "#UID" "#GID"` (replace with actual numbers - keep the number sign)

Other variants would allow you to use suPHP or suexec, setting them up as a handler for all scripts. You need to have the components compiled in and need to be using CGI/FastCGI for your PHP scripts.

Since you currently require root permissions to run that script, you cannot use only suexec. Some of your options are:

1. Change the permissions of the script - may be difficult/insecure depending on what it does (i.e. a simple chmod won't suffice if the tasks it performs require certain privileges)
2. use `sudo`, with the command,from your php script (add the user to sudoers, etc)
3. use an external script with `setuid`

The security of all of the above is questionable at best.